# unassigned expression in function

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am going through 'Python Cookbook' by Beazley and Jones and I came across the following code:

```
# Token processing functions
def t_NUM(t):
 r'\d+'
 t.value = int(t.value)
 return t
```

What I don't understand is what the purpose of `r'\d+'` is. The above example is part of a larger code which I don't expect anyone to dig into. So, consider the following MRE:

```
def func():
    1
```

This appears to be a legal function, even though `1` is not assigned. What, then, is the point of such syntax/statements inside a function?

Comment: In the second case, nothing. In the first case, a string literal that's the first statement in a function is a [docstring](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0257/).

Comment: it is syntactically valid but makes no sense - so don't.  Comments used to document your function normally are done by using triple `"` as docstrings - not sure if raw strings work the same. Try help(t_NUM) to see for yourself.

Comment: In this case it's a [docstring](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0257/). See my answer on [compsci](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/140164/why-does-python-allow-stand-alone-expressions/140174#140174) for more details

Comment: Generally,  one would like to define what a function does in the form of plain text. Docstrings are used for such purposes.

Comment: In this case the doscrting makes sense, it basically describes the format it expects the argument in (a sequence of digits)

Comment: It's a very bad example of a docstring though. And if the cookbook doesn't explain its meaning, better to ignore it.

Comment: I was used to seeing triple quoted docstrings. This one threw me off.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> What I don't understand is what the purpose of r'\d+' is.

As others have mentioned, generally speaking it's a [docstring](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0257/), the string gets attached to the function object and can be displayed by tools like [`pydoc`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pydoc.html?highlight=pydoc)/[`help`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#help), or documentation systems like [Sphinx](https://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/).

As the name indicates, it's a *documentation string*, the content would usually be an explanation of the purpose and interface (input / output / exceptions) of the function e.g. [this example from the standard library](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/049c4125f8a2b482c6129db68463f58e20c31526/Lib/bisect.py#L3-L13).

Docstrings can be define as the first statement of a `class` or `function`, at the top of a module (the rules for these are a bit more complicated), or right after some assignments ("attribute docstrings"), though most tools have trouble with the last one.

However in this specific case

> The above example is part of a larger code [...]

is *extremely* relevant: this is a parser example using  [ply](https://www.dabeaz.com/ply/), which [leverages the docstring as a tokenization pattern](https://www.dabeaz.com/ply/ply.html#ply_nn6).

> When a function is used [nb: tp specify a token], the regular expression rule is specified in the function documentation string. The function always takes a single argument which is an instance of LexToken.

So for this specific Cookbook snippet the purpose of `r'\d+'` is not documentation but to define what kind of input is considered a `NUM` token.